# Very unusual approach for Alien to disarm rifle wielding human

Tags: warfare, aliens, behaviour, humanoid

I'm writing a plot to video game (i hope i'll learn unity and make it one day). It will be 3D Adventure from First Person Perspective.
 Player Character is a modern day professional hunter. He is moving through the winter forest. It is dusk, the weather is very bad - cold and blizzard. He sees a camp-fire. He approaches it and sees two persons dressed in dark cloaks sitting near to it. Let's call them Aliens. They looks like this (but in dark cape) -

[image: somebody in cape]

Player's Character is frightened, and aims his 2 barrelled hunting rifle on them. One of Aliens does something, and  Players Character's rifle is transferred to one of Aliens.

Spoiler less background on Aliens - they are humanoids from more advanced civilization, they have scouting mission on Earth. They are in general humans (even without cape they are quite hard to distinguish from human), they possess powers like telekinesis, mesmerism, telepathy. They are very strong and fast.

My ideas:

1. One of Aliens asks: "Why are you aiming this stick on me?" And Player  realize that he is holding stick, and rifle is laying on the ground at his feet. He throws stick, takes the rifle, but it turns out that he has taken stick and thrown rifle.
2. One of Aliens flaps his hands, there is white flash, and when Player can see, he sees, that Alien is holding the rifle.
3. When Player aims rifle on Aliens, they synchronously and quickly jumps into darkness (the left one jumps to left, the right one jumps to right), and while Player tries to trace one of them, the second one approaches Player from the back and knock's him out, taking away his rifle.
4. One of Aliens drops something in campfire, there is bright flash, and when Player can see things, one of Aliens had already taken Player's rifle.
5. Just old plain telekinesis - one of Aliens raise hand, and rifle is jumping from Player's Characters' hands into Aliens' hand - kinda boring.

**Question is: how we can disarm rifle wielding human in harmless, but very bizarre, alien and unusual way?**

Requirements: it have to be fast - few seconds, and it have to really amaze the one being disarmed. And it must hint, that one is facing something really alien. Furthermore, it have to be harmless to the one being disarmed - later in game Aliens will offer quests and help to Player's.

Comment: I think this question may be too opinion based for Stack Exchange.  You've already come up with 5 ideas.  I could come up with a hundred more, because there's really no limit.  It's just the actions of one individual, and that individual's capabilities are well beyond that of any physical creature to date.

Comment: I like your aliens but this question is about plot rather than world building.  If you're looking for some feedback on your ideas feel free to bring it up in the chatroom. :) http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor

Comment: Rey: "And you'll drop your weapon."  Stormtrooper JB-007: "And I'll drop my weapon."

Comment: Something like this? https://youtu.be/BPiW0tkWfeg?t=2m29s

Comment: I don't think this question is a good fit for this (or any) Stack Exchange site, but I do have two more suggestions to add to your list. First, you could take advantage of the aliens being so similar to humans, and have the alien swap itself with the player. The player aims the rifle at the alien, the alien lowers the hood of its cloak, revealing the player's face. Suddenly the player is standing in the cloak and the alien is aiming the rifle at him. A simpler and more realistic option would be for the alien to activate a sort of electromagnet that rips the rifle from the player's hands.

Answer (score 2):

Does the human have to lose the rifle? Or would totally disabling it be acceptable?

### Cold-welding

The alien gestures at the gun; it suddenly becomes warm to the touch, and the human finds he can't pull the trigger. Further investigation shows that all metal parts have fused together where they touched, leaving the gun a useless piece of intricately carved metal.

(This is actually a thing that really happens to metals in a vacuum - if two metal surfaces are pressed together in vacuum, they can weld to one another and become a single unit)

### Teleport

The gun simply vanishes from the player's hands and appears near the camp fire.

### Distract

The alien suddenly appears to be in several places at once, or a monster of some description appears and becomes a much higher priority. Whichever alien the player shoots at turns out to have been an illusion, and the alien has closed the distance and manually taken the rifle.

### Ask nicely

Of course, this can be combined with other methods, but simply having the alien request the human lower their weapon would give the player some sense of agency, rather than just having the weapon vanish.

Comment: For losing rifle - no, human needs to receive the rifle back if he behaves good with Aliens. Ask nicely is a great idea, i'll add it as possible Players' action.

Comment: As for cold welding, Schlock Mercenary owned that approach: http://www.schlockmercenary.com/2001-03-16

Answer (score 1):

- Sympathy: the alien makes the human percieve the alien as one of the human's loved ones, confusing the human until the human agrees to stand down
- Psychedelia: when the human approaches, he begins to hallucinate odd things all around him, confusing him into submission. Bonus: This could make for some flashy special effects on screen
- Deep Space: the human suddenly perceives himself floating in deep space, with stars, planets and nebula all around and his gun floating away from him, but he doesn't care, due to cosmic amazement. Bonus: more super effects
- Bliss: the human is immediately infused with limitless bliss, bringing back all memories of everything he has ever loved in life, turning his thoughts to peace and happiness rather than cold dark strangers. This is the alien's way of conveying that they are friendly. Bonus: cool flashbacks and beautiful things